# Не могу присвоить переменной String значение другой переменной такого же типа

Tags: java, android, строки

Пишу свой проигрыватель на андроид. Дошла часть до уведомления, где мне нужно в выводимой информации указать имя исполнителя и название. Но как только я указываю эти данные приложение крашится. Пробовал всё, что знаю.
присваивали уже и переменной эти значения, начало крашиться ещё на инициализациях переменных перед запуском.

Может я не понимаю чего, подскажите.

Код - https://gist.github.com/sstzhp/27bf134e32374a294b2e

Comment: Приведите код .

Comment: вот код, два файла, Song - из которого берутся данные, MainActivity - где находятся методы, которые эти данные берут. https://gist.github.com/sstzhp/27bf134e32374a294b2e

Comment: А проблема где?

Comment: я не знаю, где проблема, не могу найти. просто присваиваю переменной значение путем String a = comm.get_title(); где comm - Communicator. дальше приложение крашится. при этом текстовым полям эти данные присваиваются без проблем.

Comment: Если приложение падает, нужно прикладывать к вопросу стэктрейс при падении. Гадать, что случилось или компилировать ваши программы у себя никому не интересно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того, что сразу бросилось в глаза:

```
public String get_album();
String get_title();
```

Если указатель доступа не объявлен, то он автоматически делает переменную package-protected. А это в свою очередь означает, что доступ к этой переменной получает только сам класс и классы внутри того же package.

Иными словами, при попытке "достать" из объекта значение переменной `get_title()` во время исполнения тот его попросту не "отдаёт".

Comment: Странно, если доступ к невидимому объекту, то вообще не должно компилироваться, не то что запускаться.

Comment: @NickVolynkin код внимательно не смотрел. Писал рано утром с телефона. Отсутствие указателя доступа резануло глаз. По-хорошему, мне следовало оформить мои подозрения в виде комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрим на метод и тренируем телепатию.

```
public String getTitle()
    {
        if (title.equals("") || title == null)
        {
            return file_name.substring(0, file_name.length() - 4);
        }
        return title;
    }
```

- Почти наверняка дело в том, что вы проверяете на `null` позже, чем вызываете метод объекта (что подразумевает, что он уже не null). В таком случае ошибка в стектрейсе называется [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).
- Кстати, а что будет, если имя файла будет меньше 4 символов? Тогда метод  [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) выкинет [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)